# DNS設定。メール送受信する際、メールアドレスのドメイン指定したい

Tags: dns, postfix

**DNS設定で、メール送受信する際、メールアドレスのドメイン指定したいのですが、

下記の違いを知りたい(何れが合っているか、それとも何れも間違っているか)**

・2つある理由は、ドメインを違う所から取得していて、それぞれのフォーマットに沿って良くわからないまま入力した結果こうなっています

---

**現状1.example.com**
・Aレコードを2つ書いた理由は、「MX指定する際予めAレコード指定が必要」とエラー表示されたため
・Aレコード指定する際「*.example.com A」と「example.com A」は同じ意味ですか？
・3600はデフォルト値で入力されていたので、そのままにしています
・メールサーバのドメインを「mail.example.com」にしようと思っているのですが、ここは何でも良いですか？

```
*.example.com A 3600 IPアドレス  
mail.example.com A 3600 IPアドレス
example.com MX 3600 mail.example.com /10
example.com TXT 3600 v=spf1 include:mail.example.com ~all
```

---

**現状2.example.net**
・この書き方だと、メールアドレスのドメイン指定は出来ていない？
・mxの10の書き方が、「現状1」と異なるのですが、「@ 10」と「/10」では何が違うのですか？
・txtの @にはどんな意味がありますか・

```
example.net * IPアドレス
mx @ 10
txt @ v=spf1 example.net:0m ~all
```

Comment: ご利用になられているDNSサーバもしくはサービスは何でしょうか？BINDもしくはAWSRoute53等命じいただくと記述方式などが違いますので、回答が分かれる可能性があります

Comment: 現状1が「お名前.com」のDNS設定で、現状2が「VALUE-DOMAIN」のコントロールパネルで、サーバはさくらVPSです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## example.com

> ・Aレコード指定する際「*.example.com A」と「example.com A」は同じ意味ですか？

おそらく違います。`*.example.com`は(他に明示的なレコードが無い限り)`任意の名前.example.com`にマッチします。`example.com`は`example.com`自体への指定だと思います。

> メールサーバのドメインを「mail.example.com」にしようと思っているのですが、ここは何でも良いですか？

好きに決めればよいです。

> `example.com TXT 3600 v=spf1 include:mail.example.com ~all`

SPFレコードを`mail.example.com`のSPFレコードを読み込むように指定していますが`mail.example.com`のSPFレコードがありません。

## example.net

`@`は(厳密には異なりますが)ドメイン自身を指します。`mx @ 10`はメールサーバとして`example.net`を優先度10で指定しています。が、この設定の範囲では、`example.net`に対するAレコードが設定されていません。`a @ (IPアドレス)`という行が必要です。

> `txt @ v=spf1 example.net:0m ~all`

書式が間違っています。例を載せておきます。

```
txt @ v=spf a:mail.exmaple.net ~all #正しく逆引きが設定されていることが必要
txt @ v=spf ip4:(IPアドレス) ~all
txt @ v=spf mx ~all
```